# Matplotlib colors not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Except for the default ['r', 'g', 'c'... ] values for colors, every single color in matplotlib returns some sort of error.

For example, the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([2, 7], [1, 4], 'C1')
plt.show();
```

produces the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/homerlogistics/Downloads/colors-1.py", line 5, in <module>
    ax.plot([2, 7], [1, 4], 'C1')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1373, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 304, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 263, in _plot_args
    linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 115, in _process_plot_format
    'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)
ValueError: Unrecognized character C in format string
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Python version 2.7.10
Matplotlib version 2.0.2

Comment: What is your desired result when you specify `"C1"`? If you want to have cyan, downward-facing triangles you need to specify `"c1"`. Note the lowercase `c`.

Comment: I do not see any reason the code from the question would not run correctly in matplotlib 2.0.2. Especially since the part that raises the error has not been changed between 2.0.2 and the current version. As a workaround one may of course specify color explicitely, (`ax.plot([2, 7], [1, 4], color='C1')`). For testing why it fails, what is the output of `import matplotlib.colors; matplotlib.colors.to_rgba("C1")`?

Comment: @user8153 "`C1`" is a valid color, see https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html

Comment: @DavidG Thank you, I did not know that. I got the same error message as the original poster, but that was in Matplotlib 1.5.1. I just tried the code snippet on a different machine with Matplotlib 2.0.0, and it works correctly there.

Comment: Using Matplotlib v2.0.2. The C1 is just a test, since the sample code on the documentation uses that. I'm actually trying to use hex values, but similarly, anything besides 'r', 'g', 'c', 'y', ... etc, produces the same type of error.

Comment: Maybe you did not get the point here: In matplotlib 2.0.2 the code from above is supposed to work correctly. Hence you are either not using that version or something else is different in your case. What you therefore need to do is to provide information about what could be different in your case and more generally what system this fails on. I even asked a very specific question in a comment above; such questions are of course meant to be answered by you if you truly want help here.

Comment: The line numbers in the error messages do not correspond to those in the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v2.0.2/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py), so I would suppose that you are not using Matplotlib 2.0.2. What is the output of `print mpl.__version__`?

Comment: @user8153 Aha, that explains it. `print mpl.__version__` outputs `1.4.3`. I mistakenly thought I had 2.0.2 since `pip show matpotlib` outputted 2.0.2. Thanks! @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry, I missed your comment.